# Why doesn't the linker find std::cout and other std entries?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, fedora, clang++

I am trying to compile a simple program using clang++ under Eclipse CDT Kepler under Fedora. Below is a clang++ compilation log run within Eclipse.

If I enter at the command prompt 'clang++ ../src/Hello\ LLVM\ and\ Clang.cc' I get no errors. If I enter the Eclipse commands I do duplicate the linkage error messages.

Various SOs and the clang mailing list said that undefined references to std::??? are caused by using clang instead of clang++ as well as use libc++ instead of libstdc++. In the 3rd and 4th line, clang++ is used. In the 4th line, stdc++.

I am using the LLVM with Clang (Linux) Eclipse defined Tool Chain.
Interesting behavior is when I select Properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor, I see LLVM with Clang (Linux) as the tool chain. If I select Linux GCC. When I go back to select from the list of Tool Chains, the LLMV with Clang (Linux) is gone! It would seem that the tool is not 'supported' but it seems to be supported. Curious.

What do I do to get clang++ to build under Eclipse CDT Kepler? The path to the libraries seems to be the key to the problem.

```
21:43:42 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Hello LLVM and Clang ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang++ -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src/Hello LLVM and Clang.bc" "../src/Hello LLVM and Clang.cc" 
clang++ -v -L/usr/lib -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/ -o "Hello LLVM and Clang" "src/Hello LLVM and Clang.bc" -lstdc++ 
clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final)
Target: i386-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
"/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-redhat-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -  disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name "Hello LLVM and Clang.bc" -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu pentium4 -target-linker-version 2.23.2 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.3 -fdebug-compilation-dir "/home/ksmith/C++PlayProjects/Hello LLVM and Clang/Debug" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fdiagnostics-show-option -backend-option -vectorize-loops -o "/tmp/Hello LLVM and Clang-mT5CWp.o" -x ir "src/Hello LLVM and Clang.bc"
clang -cc1 version 3.3 based upon LLVM 3.3 default target i386-redhat-linux-gnu
"/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o "Hello LLVM and Clang" /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../.. -L/lib -L/usr/lib "/tmp/Hello LLVM and Clang-mT5CWp.o" -lstdc++ -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../crtn.o
/tmp/Hello LLVM and Clang-mT5CWp.o: In function `main':
/home/ksmith/C++PlayProjects/Hello LLVM and Clang/Debug/../src/Hello LLVM and Clang.cc:12: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/home/ksmith/C++PlayProjects/Hello LLVM and Clang/Debug/../src/Hello LLVM and Clang.cc:13: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/home/ksmith/C++PlayProjects/Hello LLVM and Clang/Debug/../src/Hello LLVM and Clang.cc:13: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/home/ksmith/C++PlayProjects/Hello LLVM and Clang/Debug/../src/Hello LLVM and Clang.cc:13: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/tmp/Hello LLVM and Clang-mT5CWp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init':
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:74:     undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

21:43:44 Build Finished (took 1s.982ms)
```

Comment: When you build on the command line, are you using the lines above that Eclipse is emitting? Also, I know that I use `libc++` with clang++, not `libstdc++`.

Comment: @chrisaycock If I enter at the command prompt 'clang++ ../src/Hello\ LLVM\ and\ Clang.cc' I get no errors. If I enter the Eclipse commands I do duplicate the linkage error messages. I would seem that the path to the libraries is the problem. Will edit original question.

Comment: Now see what happens when you switch to `libc++`. On the command line, I have to add `-stdlib=libc++` with clang++. I'm curious if there is a similar solution for Eclipse.

Comment: @chrisaycock If I use c++ instead of stdc++, I get the linkage error lib not found, libc++. I've also added to the question a behavior I see with the Tool Chain Editor.